# Compute consecutive day streaks with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysql-5.7

I have the following table :

```
Date       | isDone
--------------------
2018-10-01 | 1
2018-10-02 | 1
2018-10-03 | 1
2018-10-04 | 1 
2018-10-10 | 0
2018-10-15 | 1
2018-10-16 | 0
2018-10-18 | 1
2018-10-19 | 1
2018-10-20 | 1
```

There can be only one row by day, with 2 possible values 0 or 1. It is not mandatory for a day to have a row. If there isn't a row for a day the value is considered as 0.

I want to compute the "current streak" of done tasks (the isDone column) from the current date. Assume we are the 2018-10-20, the result would be **3**. For now, I don't want to compute the biggest streak of the month which would be in this case **4** (from 2018-10-01 to 2018-10-04). I am wondering what is the best option to compute this, directly with SQL (MySQL 5.7) or getting raw data by day and computing the streak with PHP?

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: What a result are you expecting for 2018-10-16  ?

Comment: Version added. @splash58 the 2018-10-16 is a "1" one day streak because the 15 and 17 are both considered as 0 . But obviously, only streaks with more than 1 day will be interesting to display.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use MySQL variables to compute the streak. Basically you need to increment the streak on consecutive days when `isDone` is 1, and reset it when `isDone` is 0 or the dates are not consecutive. This query will produce the streak values for each day:

```
SELECT s.Date,
       @streak := IF(Date = @last_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND isDone = 1, @streak+1, 1) AS streak,
       @last_date := Date AS last_date
FROM status s
JOIN (SELECT @streak := 0, @last_date := '1900-01-01') i
ORDER BY s.Date
```

Output:

```
Date        streak  last_date
2018-10-01  1       2018-10-01
2018-10-02  2       2018-10-02
2018-10-03  3       2018-10-03
2018-10-04  4       2018-10-04
2018-10-10  1       2018-10-10
2018-10-15  1       2018-10-15
2018-10-16  1       2018-10-16
2018-10-18  1       2018-10-18
2018-10-19  2       2018-10-19
2018-10-20  3       2018-10-20
```

Then you can use that as a subquery to determine the streak as of a given day e.g.

```
SELECT Date, streak
FROM (SELECT s.Date,
             @streak := IF(Date = @last_date + INTERVAL 1 DAY AND isDone = 1, @streak+1, 1) AS streak,
             @last_date := Date AS last_date
      FROM status s
      JOIN (SELECT @streak := 0, @last_date := '1900-01-01') i
      ORDER BY s.Date) s
WHERE s.Date = '2018-10-20'
```

Output:

```
Date        streak
2018-10-20  3
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1089df2fd5378885b49a9ef729a245b2)

Comment: Hi @Nick, nice! Didn't know about the @ notation. I saw the filddle is using MySQL 8 to you think it will be ok with 5.7? I'll try this week. Thanks.:)

Comment: The @ notation indicates a variable. It should be fine with 5.7 there's nothing in it that depends on 8, that's just the only version on dbfiddle

Comment: Hi Nick it's now implemented on tokeeen.com ;) I don't know why but the fiddle doesn't seem to work anymore. (results are not displayed) Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @Tokeeen.com for some reason MySQL is not working on dbfiddle at the moment. If you change the DB to MariaDB (MySQL 5 compatible) and press "run" it works fine.